# validar email con Regex no funciona. ASP:NET MVC C# Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, datatables

- Cuando edito los datos de mi tabla de datos, quiero que el correo electrónico sea válido, así que tengo que poner una validación de error cuando el usuario inserta un formato de correo electrónico no válido.
- En mi controlador pongo el código para hacerlo, de modo que cuando el usuario hace clic en Guardar, se muestra el error, pero cuando se muestra el error, los datos se guardan y deben guardarse solo cuando el formato es correcto.

No sé cómo hacerlo funcionar. Tengo que usar regex. Aso no es muy efectivo mi expresión regular para validar el correo electrónico.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditData(ModelTemplateEmail modelEmail)
    {
        UpdateEmail(modelEmail.EmailId, modelEmail.userName, modelEmail.Title, 
                       modelEmail.Email,modelEmail.description, modelEmail.languageID);


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelEmail.userName))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Please enter a user name");

        }

        else if (modelEmail.userName.Length > 20)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Please enter less than 20 characters");
        }



        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelEmail.Email))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Please enter an Email");
        }
        else if (!Regex.Match(modelEmail.Email, @"^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$").Success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);


        }


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {         
            return RedirectToAction("EmailData");
        };
        MainLanguagelist();

        return View ();

    }
```

modelo

```
namespace MyMVCApplication.Models {
public class ModelTemplateEmail
{      
    [Display(Name = "EmailId")]
    public int EmailId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string userName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Title")]      
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string description { get; set; }    
    public List<ModelTemplateEmail> EmailDataList { get; set; }     
    public int languageID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Language")]
    public string MainLanguage { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Hola, edita la pregunta e indica el Modelo `ModelTemplateEmail`. Y otra cosa, por que no validas el Email en el Cliente antes de enviar el formulario al Controlador?

Comment: hola!. es que es un training en el trabajo. La cosa es que tengo la tabla que son datos de mi base de datos y en el explorador la tengo que editar entonces al editar el email tengo que poner que sea un formato valido y no me deje cambiarlo por un formato erroneo.

Comment: Deberías validar el Email en el explorador (cliente). Mírate este artículo [Validación de formularios en ASP.NET MVC - Unobtrusive Validate](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/11/12/validaci%C3%B3n-de-formularios-en-aspnet-mvc-unobtrusive-validate)

Comment: gracias!, lo intente en el modeloo pero me guardaba los datos. asi que intente por el controlador

Comment: Si sigues lo que te indica en el artículo es **imposible** que te guarde los datos, ya que nunca llegarán los datos al Controlador.

Comment: ya pero no encontre la manera de saber que tengo que hacer en el controlador para que funcione. pensaba que era poniendo          if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("EmailData");
            };
            MainLanguagelist();

            return View();

Comment: vale ya entiendo porque no me guardaba, no lo habia puesto en el orden que tenia que ser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mejor utilizar una función que te diga si es un email válido. La comprobación es algo más compleja de lo que planteas. Te dejo la recomendación de [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-verify-that-strings-are-in-valid-email-format?redirectedfrom=MSDN) al respecto.
El código de Microsoft lo hace creando una clase llamada `RegexUtilities`, pero tu puedes utilizar la que más te convenga, sin necesidad de crear una nueva.

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class RegexUtilities

Public Shared Function IsValidEmail(email As String) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email) Then Return False
    ' Use IdnMapping class to convert Unicode domain names.
    Try
        'Examines the domain part of the email and normalizes it.
        Dim DomainMapper =
            Function(match As Match) As String
                'Use IdnMapping class to convert Unicode domain names.
                Dim idn = New IdnMapping
                'Pull out and process domain name (throws ArgumentException on invalid)
                Dim domainName As String = idn.GetAscii(match.Groups(2).Value)
                Return match.Groups(1).Value & domainName           
            End Function

        'Normalize the domain
        email = Regex.Replace(email, "(@)(.+)$", DomainMapper,
                              RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
    Catch e As RegexMatchTimeoutException
        Return False
    Catch e As ArgumentException
        Return False
    End Try
    Try
        Return Regex.IsMatch(email,
                             "^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
                             "(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-0-9a-z]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$",
                             RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250))
    Catch e As RegexMatchTimeoutException
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

End Class
```

Para llamarla, simplemente haces referencia a la función:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelEmail.Email))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Please enter an Email");
        }
        else if (RegexUtilities.IsValidEmail(modelEmail.Email))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Evidentemente, es posible que ya tengas de una clase de utilidades, puedes poner la función en ella, en vez de crear esta, luego la llamarías con `NombreDeTuClase.IsValidEmail(modelEmail.Email)`. Eso si, ten presente que en tu clase deberás hacer referencia a los ensamblados `System.Globalization` y `System.Text.RegularExpressions` con un `import`.

Comment: gracias!. no entiendo todo eso perdona soy principiante. eso lo tengo que pober en mi action result?

Comment: He editado la respuesta, a ver si queda más claro. Lo importante es la función. Esta función la pones donde quieras y la llamas tal como te indico.

Comment: gracias! lo intentare asi, no no tengo una clase de utilidades